# AWS ElasticSearch as a Service fails to connect via standalone KIBANA

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, kibana

I have ElasticSearch as a service on AWS. What I have done is installed a 6.1.2 Kibana on a different EC2 Instance and trying to connect it. My Policy are in place and I can browse the endpoint from the EC2 instance.

However when i change Kibana.yml to point to the endpoint from ES AWS Service it turns RED.

### AWS ES Endpoint Successful call from the said EC2 where standalone KIBANA is installed

```
{
    "name" : "BBXYZ",
    "cluster_name" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "cluster_uuid" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "version" : {
    "number" : "6.0.1",
    "build_hash" : "d951bbf",
    "build_date" : "2017-12-07T01:43:54.348Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.0.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
    },
    "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

### Kibana Version 6.1.2

Kibana Error : Status Red
**plugin:elasticsearch@6.1.2  Request Timeout after 3000ms**

Please help; do i need to have KIBANA AND AWS ES ON THE SAME VERSION. AWS ES IS ON 6.0

The reason why ui am installing standalone KIBANA is because we want to enable login and disable actions on the KIBANA for few

Comment: Are the ports in security group open in EC2 ?

Comment: I can access the AWS ES endpoint on the browser on the said EC2 ? Anything else i need to check.

Comment: Have you added the `http` prefix and explicitly specify port `80`. Because as per the AWS documentation you need to explicitly specify these two. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-kibana.html#es-kibana-local

Comment: @VaisakhPS thanks for that pointer - it helped me resolve the timeout issue but now I am facing the following error.

This version of Kibana requires Elasticsearch v6.1.2 on a
ll nodes. I found the following incompatible nodes in your cluster: v6.0.1

I wanted to have 6.1.2 so i can enable login credentials and set roles.

Do you see any options ?

Comment: ROLE MANAGEMENT in lower versions of Kibana ?

Comment: @Tub The Kibana version you are using is `6.1.x` but the awselasticsearch version is `6.0.x` so either try to downgrade your kibana to `6.0.x` or install a standalone elasticsearch which is compatible to your kibana version.

Comment: @VaisakhPS can you please enter your answer so i can accept it. Your answer to add port 80 at the end worked, that was a miss from my end for the problem i had in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tub As per the AWS documentation to connect a standalone Kibana server to Amazon ElasticSearch you need to add the `http` prefix and explicitly specify port `80`.  For example `elasticsearch_url: "http://elasticsearch_domain_endpoint:80"`.

For more please Refer here [Connecting a Local Kibana Server to Amazon ES](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-kibana.html#es-kibana-local)